# nginx 403 Forbidden error

Tags: nginx, docker, graphite, grafana

I'm trying to set up graphite to work with grafana in docker based on this project : https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite

and when I run my dockerfile I get 403 Forbidden error for nginx.

my configurations for nginx are almost the same as the project's configurations. I run my dockerfiles on a server and test them on my windows machine. So the configurations are not exactly the same ... for example I have :

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;
location / {
  root /src/grafana/dist;
  index index.html;
}
location /graphite/ {
    proxy_pass                 http:/myserver:8000/;
    proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept";
}
```

But I still keep getting 403 forbidden. Checking the error log for nginx says :

```
 directory index of "/src/grafana/dist/" is forbidden
```

Stopping and running it again it says :

```
 directory index of "/src/grafana/dist/" is forbidden
```

I'm very new to nginx ... was wondering if there's something in the configurations that I'm misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because you are hitting the first location block and the index file is not found.

Comment: ah I see. I just looked in the /src/grafana/dist and there's no index.html. I'm assuming I have to add the index.html file manually?

Answer (score 5):

A request to '/' will look for 'index.html' in '/src/grafana/dist'.

Confirm that:
1. 'index.html' exists.
2. You have the right permissions.
nginx has read-access to the entire directory tree leading up to 'index.html'. That is, it must be able to read directories 'src', 'src/grafana' and 'src/grafana/dist' as well as 'index.html' itself. 
A hacky quick-fix to achieve this would be to do 'sudo chmod -R 755 /src', but I don't recommend it.

Comment: So what *do* you recommend?